# Slicing Data From a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, slice

I have code that will correctly return a list of xyz coordinates (or a list of xyz coordinates). My problem is that I want to directly access the individual numbers from the lists it returns, but I can only access a whole list at a time. My code:

```
import numpy as np
a = [([2, -2, 0.29]), ([-2, 0, 1.9]), ([2, 1, 2.35]), ([2, -3, 2.96])]
b = [0,2,3]
myZip= list(zip(a,b))
result={}
for x in myZip:
    result.setdefault(x[1],[]).append(x[0])
xyz=[]
for each_index in b:
     xyz.append(result[each_index])
     print(xyz)
     xyz.clear()
```

will return:

```
[[[2, -2, 0.29]]]
[[[-2, 0, 1.9]]]
[[[2, 1, 2.35]]]
```

I now want to split this into X and Y so that X=[2,-2,2] and Y=[-2,0,1]. I have tried slicing it directly, but I get an error about the slice being integers and not tuples. I also tried converting to numpy then using np.hsplit. How can this be achieved? Thanks guys(or girls).

*EDIT*

I realize that in these cases it would only print one at a time, but in my real world example, there are times where it will return ([x,y,x],[x,y,z]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> X = [result[i][0][0] for i in b]
>>> Y = [result[i][0][1] for i in b]
>>> print X, Y
[2, -2, 2] [-2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip(*a)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = [[2, -2, 0.29], [-2, 0, 1.9], [2, 1, 2.35], [2, -3, 2.96]]

>>> b = [0,2,3]

>>> x, y, z = zip(*(a[i] for i in b))

>>> x
(2, 2, 2)

>>> y
(-2, 1, -3)

>>> z
(0.29, 2.35, 2.96)
```

By the way, the round brackets inside your list were redundant so I removed them.